# Uniform Direction for Line Directions

Tags: structural-analysis, beam, ansys, meshing, ansys-apdl

[image]

Despite several similar questions and my efforts, there is still no solution so far.

Presently, ANSYS gives Directions to Lines on its own which are **flipped** even for two collinear lines. As a results Beam sections are flipped at KPs.

Tried using Section orientation through Keypoints but since Line normals are flipped this does not solve my problem.

I require **uniform** assignment of direction based on a particular WP.

Please help.

Comment: Again, please provide a few `MAPDL` lines to build a simple working example.

Comment: Asking for a solution to one problem in multiple questions is a bad practice here, you should instead edit the original question, adding helpful information. Your problem is beam section alignment, not line direction. Although flipping line direction seems to rotate this particular section, it effectively mirrors it. Beam section alignment in general is combination of line direction and another vector, which is usually defined by a node or a keypoint. So one of the reasons you are not getting an answer you like may be that people just don't solve problem you have in the manner you insist upon.